# how to go to the parent page in Nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, nuxt.js, router

let's say I have this url in my Nuxt.js:

```
http://localhost:3000/sectionOne/someId/player
```

and I want to go to the `someId` page:

```
http://localhost:3000/sectionOne/someId
```

I have written this code but it just refreshes the page. How can I fix it?

```
      let hasan = Object.assign({}, this.$route);
      let hosein = delete hasan.params.player;
      this.$router.go({ hosein });
```

Comment: Hi, Can you share code for how you have defined your routes?

Comment: It's in Nuxtjs so the routing is pre-defined. Also updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing/#nested-routes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `replace`, go is used for going back to pages. To push on a new path, use the `replace` or `push`.

First what we will do is to get the current path and replace the text **'/player'** with **empty space**. Then we can use any two examples to do our work.

Here is a example with your code with `replace`:

```
let newUrl = this.$route.path.replace('/player', '')
this.$router.replace(newUrl);
```

Here is another one with `push`:

```
let newUrl = this.$route.path.replace('/player', '')
this.$router.push(newUrl);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this to nav to the parent

`<nuxt-link :to="'../' + post.fields.slug">{{post.fields.title}}</nuxt-link>`